# Error while trying to bring system_alert_window in android using flutter when app is closed

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I tired to solve this by using `android_alarm_manager_plus` to schedule the background event at a particular time. And moreover till now that works fine, but to show the  pop-up I used the package `system_alert_window` from `pub.dev`. As long as the app is open in the background the pop-up works and it displays as an overlay. But when the alarm event triggers when the app is closed, it pops up you app has crashed

So summing up : The system_alert_window when called as long as the app is open, it works. But when called when app is closed, it crashes.

Please someone help me with a solution or a way around this.

Android version used to test 11 & 12

**Permissons List**

```dart
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE " />
    <!-- For apps with targetSDK=31 (Android 12) -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
```

**Code used to open Pop up**

```dart
import 'package:android_alarm_manager_plus/android_alarm_manager_plus.dart';
import 'package:system_alert_window/system_alert_window.dart' as alw;
import './system_alert.dart';

bool _alarmStatus = false;
  static void printHello() {
    final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    final int isolateId = Isolate.current.hashCode;
    alw.SystemAlertWindow.showSystemWindow(
      height: 230,
      header: header,
      body: body,
      footer: footer,
      margin: alw.SystemWindowMargin(left: 8, right: 8, top: 100, bottom: 0),
      gravity: alw.SystemWindowGravity.TOP,
      notificationTitle: "Incoming Call",
      notificationBody: "+1 646 980 4741",
      prefMode: alw.SystemWindowPrefMode.OVERLAY,
    );
    AndroidAlarmManager.cancel(696969);
    AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
      const Duration(seconds: 20),
      20070,
      printHello,
    );
  }

  void _setAlarm() async {
    final int helloAlarmID = 696969;
    await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
      const Duration(seconds: 15),
      helloAlarmID,
      printHello,
    );
    setState(() {
      _alarmStatus = !_alarmStatus;
    });
  }
```

Crash Logs -

```
01-10 01:07:54.195 3397 3397 E AndroidRuntime: at dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService.onCreate(AlarmService.java:351) 
01-10 01:07:54.195 3397 3397 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4307) 
01-10 01:07:54.195 3397 3397 E AndroidRuntime: ... 8 more 
01-10 01:07:54.201 2225 3489 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=data_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2 01-10 
01:07:54.211 2225 2324 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver 
01-10 01:07:54.212 2225 2324 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
```

Comment: Means you want to show popup when your app is not active or in background?

Comment: Practically yes. I want to do it. If the app runs in background there isn't a error. But when I tried to do the same without app running in background the code crashes.

Comment: Bro how did you that, I am trying to implement ```system_alert_window``` but I am getting this error
```One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to E:\Code\KnoCall\ovrly_test\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
  compileSdkVersion 34
  ...
}
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this in your AndroidManifest.xml file under `application tag`

```
android:name = "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
```

Comment: Yea I added that

Comment: Did you add the required stuff in `Application Class`?

Comment: Yes I have added

Comment: O and I just got a new discovery. It doesn't work in Android 11 and 12. Works fine in lower versions

Answer (score 0):

```
 AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
      Duration(seconds: 10),
      0,
      printHello,
      wakeup: true,
    ).then((val) => print(val));
```

---

**Make wakeup : true**

Comment: Yes already tried it. It still crashes. Added the crash log to the question

Comment: O and I just got a new discovery. It doesn't work in Android 11 and 12. Works fine in lower versions

Comment: then there might be any permission issue , please allow the permission from phone and try again .